# How can i check if a given url is within a certain domain? PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, api

How can i check if a given url is within a certain predetermined domain, say user register for api requests from:

```
http://domain.com
```

Then he makes a request from:

```
http://domain.com/script.ext?var=foo //this should validate true

http://example.com/script.ext?var=foo //this should validate false

http://www.domain.com/script.ext?var=foo //this should validate true also
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this difficult - do a sub string of the requested url

Comment: Grab `gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);` and compare that with `domain.com`

Comment: @AdrianCornish `http://malicious.com/domain.com/something` will match `domain.com` if you simply use substring.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php):

```
if ( 'domain.com' == parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ) )
{
    // do something awesome
}
```

Comment: Note that this gets the whole hostname, and not just the domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if you want to see where a request is originating from you can use the "http referer" field, that is available within the http header. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)

I'm not very good at php, but I think you can use something like $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get hold of the value. The value is set automatically, so you just need to read it.

Lets say you call a page "www.domain.com/page.php" by clicking a link on the page "www.domain.com/referer.php", then the request will have the referer field "http://www.domain.com/referer.php" when you read $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] within "www.domain.com/page.php".

If you request the "www.domain.com/page.php" by directly typing it into a browser, you get referer = null and if you click a link on www.anotherdomain.com that goes to "www.domain.com/page.php" you will get referer = http://www.anotherdomain.com.

Then you just need to compare the domain part of this value with the domain/domains that you allow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.